# Magento 2: Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists

Tags: import, url-rewriting, magento2, magento-2.0

I am trying to import product in magento 2.0 website. website contain 2 store. But when i import the product it is showing below exception:-

Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists.

i have already researched all the topic for same but still facing same issue. Please help me if anybody know the solution for same.

Thanks in advance.